# Printing string with a number of limitations

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, memory-management

Yesterday, when the lecturer asked me to ensure whether I am familiar with
pointers, I told him that I am utterly acquainted and it even seemed quite easy to me.

However, I think I've made a terrible mistake, because then he assigned me the task to print "I am very ignoble" using all the standard data types (no pointers declared) and `printf` with only one argument to it and without type casting, character literals, arithmetic or loops.
He said that programmers learn how to adapt in extremely limited/nearly impossible situations on this way.
All my tries since then were leading to a dead end.

And I am not even a programmer.

Comment: What does "using all the standard data types" mean?  You have to use a variable of each possible type?  Or does he mean "using only the standard data types"?  Are arrays allowed?  (They are not pointers, so there isn't an obvious proscription.)

Answer (score 2):

Your lecturer seems very cruel. Not because of the task, but because of the phrase he wants
you to print.

---

Assuming the question was "How can I print a string without actually.. printing a string" then my question may be valid.

---

Anyway, the first thing you need to do in such cases is to completely understand the task.
And if you do.. you would notice that the size of the phrase he wants you to print is
guaranteed to be the size of `sizeof(char) + sizeof(short) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(long long)` (especially on x64 bit architectures)
and that is 1 + 2 + 4 + 8.. 15.
So he probably wants you to use a structure in order to have these all packed and have enough space for the string, without manual allocation.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define phrase "I am very ignoble"

struct DATATYPES
{
    unsigned char      first;  // I
    unsigned short     second; // am
    size_t             third;  // very
    unsigned long long fourth; // ignoble\0
} datatypes;

int main (void)
{
    memmove(&datatypes, phrase, sizeof(phrase));

    printf("%s", &datatypes);

    return(0);
}
```

Compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` 0 errors, 0 warnings with minGW compiler..
Well-defined behavior, relatively safe

Comment: `size_t` can be more (or less) than 4 bytes and is not a standard type, `short` is not necessarily 2 bytes, padding is likely included (at least swap the types: large to small). Further: you think that helps OP? That code trades undefined behaviour for fullfilling the requirement. An idioti* lesson imo. (the latter does not go to you!).

Comment: @malina This does not meet the requirement - 'and printf with only one argument to it'.  Your solution has two arguments to printf.

Comment: @Olaf Not like your comment is all appropriate. `size_t` was required in the OP's task, so I had to use despite it being non-standard. More or less it is at least implementable.. and I specifically warned him that it is 4 bytes in most of the x64 architectures. If it is more.. that does not interfere anyway!

Comment: @FredK I believe it is intended to be one additional variadic argument to it, otherwise it makes no logical sense.

Comment: `size_t` **is** standard (in the sense that the standard requires it to be defined). It is just none of the [standard integer types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p4) (and p6). I also do not see where OP states to have to use `size_t`, but the _standard _data types_, which would include the floats, _Complex, _Imaginary and `_Bool` along with `int` and `long`. Btw: On linux x64, `sizeof(size_t)` is 8, not 4. Not sure, however, what about Windows x64 - please verify.

Comment: Yes it is, it is a type defined `unsigned int`
And is defined in many of the standard libraries.. On windows x64 it is 4 bytes. so as int. Well it is almost the same if I put `unsigned int` and `size_t` ..this doesn't prevent my solution from being a solution.

Comment: @Malina I agree it makes no sense unless the one argument is the variadic arg. But the solution still doesn't really meet the requirement of 'no pointers declared', because the type of "&datatypes" is a pointer to struct DATATYPES, unless you count it as not explicitly declared since it doesn't use a '*'.

 Really, the wording of the requirements is quite sloppy.

Comment: @Malina I think there is another problem. I believe you need a few more char variables in between the 'first, 'second', 'third', and fourth variables in order to account for the spaces between the words.

Comment: You are right about the second. It causes stack overflow in a friendly memory area.. and might be problematic for barely-optimized compilers and certainly a terrible practice (though it is not horrific, it's wrong, and I wouldn't even call it "practice"). For the first.. this is passing an argument by reference.. I didn't really DECLARE a type as a pointer as it was described as a constraint in those.. terrifying requirements here >>"(no pointers declared)"

Comment: this answer will not work for both big endian and little endian architectures and somewhat depends on a 32bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way:

```
printf( "I am very ignoble\n" );
```

no pointers, no arrays, nothing